Collision between Microsoft.Identity.Client.Desktop and Microsoft.WindowsAppSdk in WinUI 3
I would like to know, how to solve error like this:

error NETSDK1152: Found multiple publish output files with the same relative path:
MyProject\obj\x64\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\MsixContent\Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll
microsoft.web.webview2\1.0.864.35\lib\netcoreapp3.0\Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll.

This error appeared when I downloaded Microsoft.Identity.Client.Desktop, which also contains WebView2. Microsoft.Identity.Client.Desktop was needed to authorize through embedded webview, because PublicClientApplicationBuilder isn't working correctly for me. Exception says:

Original exception: AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'.

To reproduce this bug, you need to do this steps:

Download Microsoft.Identity.Client.Desktop, Microsoft.Graph and MicrosoftWindowsAppSdk.
Copy this code:

public class AuthenticationHelper
{
    static string clientId = App.Current.Resources["ida:ClientID"].ToString();
    public static string[] Scopes = { "Files.Read" };

    private static readonly IPublicClientApplication IdentityClientApp;

    public static string TokenForUser = null;
    public static DateTimeOffset Expiration;

    private static GraphServiceClient graphClient = null;

    static AuthenticationHelper()
    {
        IdentityClientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
            .WithDefaultRedirectUri()
            .WithWindowsEmbeddedBrowserSupport()
            .Build();
    }

    public static GraphServiceClient GetAuthenticatedClient()
    {
        if (graphClient == null)
        {
            // Create Microsoft Graph client.
            try
            {
                graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
                    new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                        async (requestMessage) =>
                        {
                            var token = await GetTokenForUserAsync();
                            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
                            requestMessage.Headers.Add("SampleID", "uwp-csharp-photobrowser-sample");

                        }));
                return graphClient;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Could not create a graph client: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        return graphClient;
    }

    public static async Task<string> GetTokenForUserAsync()
    {
        AuthenticationResult authResult;

        var accounts = await IdentityClientApp.GetAccountsAsync();
        var firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();

        try
        {
            authResult = await IdentityClientApp.AcquireTokenSilent(Scopes, firstAccount).ExecuteAsync();
            TokenForUser = authResult.AccessToken;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //this.logger.Error(ex);
            if (TokenForUser == null || Expiration <= DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5))
            {
                authResult = await IdentityClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(Scopes)
                    .WithAccount(firstAccount)
                    .WithPrompt(Microsoft.Identity.Client.Prompt.SelectAccount)
                    .WithUseEmbeddedWebView(true)
                    .ExecuteAsync();

                TokenForUser = authResult.AccessToken;
                Expiration = authResult.ExpiresOn;
            }
        }

        return TokenForUser;
    }
}

But same code as the one I attached above is perfectly working for me on WPF, but not working in WinUI, because Microsoft.Identity.Client 5.0+ isn't supporting some classes from UWP example.
I tried to add extern aliases to WindowsAppSdk and Microsoft.Identity.Client.Desktop, so when app is compiled it should be recognized as other WebView2, but it hadn't helped. I also tried to add ignoring of error with duplicates using ErrorOnDuplicatePublishOutputFiles, but it hadn't helped also

Downloading Microsoft.Identity.Client.Desktop and MicrosoftWindowsAppSdk. are clearly no enough to demonstrate the problem, pieces of code are not enough, please post a minimal, reproducible example How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
